# JPA Native Query to map One to Many

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have a complex Oracle query which for simplicity's sake looks like this;

```
SQL> SELECT d.id AS dept_id,
  2    d.name AS dept_name,
  3    e.id AS emp_id,
  4    e.name AS emp_name,
  5    e.dept_id AS emp_dept_id
  6  FROM drs2_dept d, drs2_emp e
  7  WHERE d.id = e.dept_id (+)
  8  /

   DEPT_ID DEPT_NAME           EMP_ID      EMP_NAME      EMP_DEPT_ID
---------- ------------------- ---------- -------------- -----------
         1 SALES                       101 JOHN                    1
         1 SALES                       102 JANE                    1
         2 ADMIN
```

My `Department` class is;

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "Department.employeeMapping",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = Department.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "DEPT_ID", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "DEPT_NAME")
            }
        ),
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = Employee.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "EMP_ID", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "EMP_NAME"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "EMP_DEPT_ID", type = Integer.class)
            }
        )
    }
)

@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "Department.findAllEmployees",
    query = "SELECT d.id AS dept_id, " + 
            "  d.name AS dept_name,  " +
            "  e.id AS emp_id,  " +
            "  e.name AS emp_name " +
            "  e.dept_id AS emp_dept_id, " +
            "FROM drs2_dept d, drs2_emp e " +
            "WHERE d.id = e.dept_id (+)",
    resultSetMapping = "Department.employeeMapping"
)

@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id // JPA will not start without it.
    Integer id;  
    String name;

    @OneToMany // JPA will not start without it.
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public Department(Integer id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Department() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

My `Employee` class is;

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id Integer id;
    Integer departmentId;
    String name;

    public Employee(Integer id, String name, Integer departmentId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public Employee() {}

    // getters and setters
}
```

Because I am using `@ConstructorResult` I am able to get the data, but it still in a flat structure, that is to say a `List<Object[]>` with three entries, each containing `[Department, Employee]`. So I have to do the following to move the `Employee` records within their respective `Department`;

```
@Component
public class DepartmentDAO  {

    @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;

    public Collection<Department> getAllDepartments() {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Department.findAllEmployees");

        Map<Integer, Department> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Object[]> list = query.getResultList();
        for (Object[] tuple: list) {
            Department d = (Department) tuple[0];
            if (! map.containsKey(d.getId())) {
                map.put(d.getId(), d);
            }
            d = map.get(d.getId());
            Employee e = (Employee) tuple[1];
            if (e.getId() != null) {
                d.getEmployees().add(e);
            }
        }
        return map.values();
    }
}
```

Whenever I add any additional properties to the `@OneToMany` I seem to get spurious SQL generated in the Hibernate logs which is incorrect (i.e. non-existent column or table names), but as I stated at the start of this question, I want the native SQL only - I don't want Hibernate to figure out what I am trying to do.

Is there any way to get JPA/Hibernate to put the `Employee` objects into the `Department`'s list for me?

(
As a sub-note, I have seen this question asked here, but either never answered or answered back in 2011, by which time JPA and Hibernate may have progressed.

I should also add that elsewhere in my project I already have `Department` and `Employee` fully mapped for `CrudRepository` use with `@Table` and `@Column`, however their `@OneToMany` definitions do not depict what I am doing in the above query, hence their absence in my example code.
)

Comment: would you be able to find any solution for this scenario? I am looking around for a solution for the same.

Comment: @user2723039 I didn’t find a solution. I was using Spring, so ended up using RowMapper. Therefore I lost the benefits to ‘@Table’ and ‘@Column’

Answer (score 0):

This query does not have any clause that forces it to be implemented with a native.
In fact it is considered a bad practice.

Try this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Departament> cq = cb.createQuery(Departament.class);

Root<Departament> rootDepartament = cq.from(Departament.class);
Join<Departament,Employee> joinEmployee = rootDepartament.join(Departament_.employees,JoinType.Left);

cq.select(rootDepartament);

List<Departament> result = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```